# Critical error -> c0000374

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When i try to compile my program I'm getting error c0000374... What can cause that?
During, debugger go into initGlobalVectorP() function, then it crash.
Allocating data to memory can influence on that problem?

```
FemGrid::FemGrid(int dimension)
{
    this->dimension = dimension;

    initGlobalMatrixH();
    initGlobalVectorP();
}

FemGrid::~FemGrid()
{
    free(*globalMatrixH);
    free(globalMatrixH);
    free(globalVectorP);

}

void FemGrid::initGlobalMatrixH()
{
    globalMatrixH = static_cast<double**>(malloc(sizeof(int) * dimension));
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        globalMatrixH[i] = static_cast<double*>(malloc(sizeof(int) * dimension));
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
        {
            globalMatrixH[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

void FemGrid::initGlobalVectorP()
{
    globalVectorP = static_cast<double*>(malloc(sizeof(int) * dimension));

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        globalVectorP[i] = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you allocate `4*dimension` amount of space in bytes, but in `for` loops you expect that you allocated `8*dimension` amount of space in bytes (and go through it all, hitting the unallocated space boundary which is at `dimension/2`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `malloc`s you're using `sizeof(int)` instead of `sizeof(double)`.

Also your destructor only deletes the first row of `globalMatrixH`. It should be a loop going through every index, just as in the construction.

Comment: Lol, that was it. I had to use `sizeof(double)` instead of `sizeof(int)`. Thanks.